# Working out program running time?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I am trying to work out the running time of my splitting program,

```
void splitX(int x) {
     if (x<=1) {return x;};
     splitX(n/2);
     System.out.println("splitting in progress");
     splitX(n/2);
     splitX(n/2);
     splitX(n/2);
}
```

I am fairly new to this, this is what  have done so far;

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2)
     = 4^2T(n/2^2)
     = 4^3T(n/2^3)
     = 4^kT(n/2^k)
     = O(log n)
```

Am i on the right track, im getting a little confused, also do you have to account for the printing line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analyzis is true until the end, the solution is `T(n) = O(n^2)`

Note that `4^kT(n/2^k) != O(log n)` since `4^k` is not a constant.

Have a look at the analyzis:

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) = 
     = 4^2T(n/2^2)
     = 4^3T(n/2^3)
     = 4^kT(n/2^k)
     = 4^log(n)*T(1) =
     = 4^log(n) * 1 =
     = (2^log(n))^2 =
     = n^2
     = O(n^2)
```

To formally prove it: we use [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

base: `T(1) = 1 = 1^2`

Assume `T(n) = n^2`  for each `k <= n`

`T(2n) = 4*T(n) =(induction hypothesis) 4*n^2 = (2n)^2`

Thus the induction hypothesis is true and `T(n) = n^2`

You can also check this result on [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%20=%204T%28n/2%29,%20T%281%29%20=%201)

Comment: thanks for this, could you explain how the 4 at the front makes a difference? would changing it to 3 for example change the run time?

Comment: @Lunar: yes. The "4 at the front" causes the formula to be "power of". Note that your analyzis got `T(n) = 4^k * T(n/2^k)`m which leads you to `4 * 4 * ... * 4` [logn times]. If it was "3 at the front" - it would have been `3 * 3 * ... *3` [logn times] which is `3^logn` [bigger then `n`, smaller then `n^2`]

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you make log(N) calls to your recursive function. multiplying this by a constant - 4-  does not change complexity, nor does the printing line (for all homework related needs).

Comment: This is plain wrong, since the "constant" is 4^k, which is not a constant. the answer is `T(n) = O(n^2)`. You can check the result in my answer or in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+4T%28n%2F2%29%2C+T%281%29+%3D+1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Big-O notation it's O(log n) mulltiply by constant.

Comment: This is plain wrong, since the "constant" is 4^k, which is not a constant. the answer is `T(n) = O(n^2)`. You can check the result in my answer or in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+4T%28n%2F2%29%2C+T%281%29+%3D+1)

Answer (score 0):

the expression is of form

**T(n)=4T(n/2) + c**

now apply master theorum using a=4, b=2 and f(n)=c;

**T(n)=O(n^loga) //base 2**

**T(n)=n^2**